# Validate characters and numbers in mixed data

Tags: c#, regex

I have created the following search patterns:

**1)** Search numbers within given range and excludes specific numbers *(excludes 1,2,8)*

```
 string numberPattern = @"^([3-7|9 ]*)$";
```

**2)** Search letters within given range and excludes specific characters *(excludes B,V)*

```
string characterPattern = @"^(?:(?![BV])[A-Z ])+$";
```

And there can be three kind of inputs:

- Input can be just characters: `ANRPIGHSAGASGG`
- Input can be just numbers: `34567934567967`
- Input can be letters and numbers: `9ANRPIG34HS56A`

**Question:** 
Is there a way to tell regex, if using number pattern then it ignores characters and same for character pattern, that it would ignore numbers? The data just can be mixed, in mixed order, I just don't see other way than grouping numbers and characters in different lists and then use related pattern. 
Is there a way to accomplish that using only regex?

Comment: Any reason not to just have three different Regex for the three situations? You could dynamically create them pretty easily given their relatively simple nature...

Comment: @Chris As I understand, if input contains characters then first pattern, if numbers then second and if both then third? But still, the third stays the same in complexity.

Comment: In fact is there any issue with just a single regex that does `^[3-79AC-UW-Z]*$`? Or are you told that the input is only numbers and need to validate it as such? It sounds like you are determining the input type by examining it which means that a single Regex would work (eg if it is just numbers the fact you are allowing letters is irrelevant)...

Comment: Do you need to combine these regexps into 1 allowing the digits and letters from your range?

Comment: @Chris No, there can be a single regex expression. I just split them into two, because they were conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
^[3-79A-Z -[BV]]*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B3-79A-Z%20-%5BBV%5D%5D*%5Cr%3F%24&i=ANRPIGHSAGASGG%0D%0A34567934567967%0D%0A9ANRPIG34HS56A%0D%0A1ANRPIG34HS56A%0D%0A2ANRPIG34HS56A%0D%0A0ANRPIG34HS56A%0D%0A8ANRPIG34HS56A%0D%0A4ANRPIG34HS56V%0D%0A4ANRPIG34HS56B&o=m).

**Details**:

- `^` - a start of a string anchor
- `[3-79A-Z -[BV]]*` - zero or more (`*`) characters:

  - `3-79A-Z`  - digits from `3` to `7`, `9`, uppercase ASCII letters and a space *except* `B` and `V` ASCII letters (the `-[BV]` is a character class subtraction construct)
- `$` - end of string anchor.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed! Also, found out about regexstorm site.

Answer (score 2):

Put it into a more readable state so you can maintain it.

`^(?:[0-9A-Z](?<![128BV]))+$`

Explained

```
 ^                        # Beginning of string
 (?:                      # Cluster group
      [0-9A-Z]                 # Initially allow  0-9 or A-Z
      (?<! [128BV] )           # Qualify, not 1,2,8,B,V
 )+                       # End cluster, must be at least 1 character
 $                        # End of string
```